# Query given keys

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to accomplish some sort of hybrid solution between `ndb.get_multi()` and `Query()`.

I have a set of keys, that I can use with:

```
entities = ndb.get_multi(keys)
```

I would like to query, filter, and order these entities using Query() or some more efficient way than doing all myself in the Python code manually.

How do people go about doing this? I want something like this:

```
query = Entity.gql('WHERE __key__ in :1 AND prop1 = :2 ORDER BY prop2', keys, 'hello')
entities = query.fetch()
```

Edit:

The above code works just fine, but it seems like fetch() never uses values from cache, whereas ndb.get_multi() does. Am I correct about this? If not, is the gql+fetch method much worse than get_multi+manual processing?

Comment: I could. From my understanding, when I do ndb.get_multi() it uses the values from cache if available (which I _really_ prefer), but when I fetch() using query, it does not use use cache. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There are no way to use a query on already fetched properties, unless you will write it by yourself, but all this stuff can be easily done with built-in python filters. Note that its more efficient to run a query if you have a big dataset, rather than `get_multi` hundreds of keys to get only 5 entities.

```
entities = ndb.get_multi(keys)
# filtering
entities = [e for e in entities if e.prop1 == 'bla' and e.prop2 > 3]
#sorting by multiple properties
entities = sorted(entities, key=lambda x: (x.prop1, x.prop2))
```

UPDATE: And yes, cache is only used when you receive your entity by key, it is *not* used when you query for entities.